# can you allocate memory on disk for the life of a process?

Tags: memory, hard-disk

How does Linux manage where on disk it will write? I know df gives the number of unused blocks, but how can I get the specific offsets of unused blocks.

More generally, I am wondering if there is a way to allocate memory on a hard drive for the life of a process (as opposed to a permanent mount) and use whatever mechanism Linux uses to manage memory on disk on that subset of memory.

I know there is something like fallocate, but that seems to be used for files.

Comment: Shouldn't you just read the document and source code? By the way, memory and disk are two different thing, it doesn't make any sense to say " locate free memory on disk".

Comment: Voted to migrate to Stackoverflow since this appears to be a programming question, not a Unix question.

Comment: @StephenHarris I modified the question to be more Linux focused.

Comment: The standard mechanism to "manage memory on disk" is called *a filesystem*  and it handles getting the specific offsets of unused blocks for you. Allocating hard drive space for the life of a process? That is called *a temporary file*, and in any filesystem with POSIX semantics, you just open a file for r/w access and immediately delete (unlink) it. As long as the file is still held open by your process, it will be perfectly usable; but when it is closed for any reason, including your program crashing or getting killed, the filesystem driver will automatically clean it up.

Comment: If you want to access disk blocks directly, you'll usually need an area of a disk that is not handled by any filesystem driver, so that your program won't conflict with it. That is typically called a *raw (data) disk/partition/logical volume*. You would need to dedicate an entire disk/partition/LV for your application's exclusive use, and then your application would have to do *all* the management of used & unused blocks within that storage space. Your question really sounds as if you were trying to re-invent the job of a filesystem somehow, so why are regular files not suitable to you?

Comment: @telecom As a learning exercise, I wanted to implement a b-tree index structure on disk. A b-tree is performant as an index structure because data is written in contiguous blocks in possibly many different areas of the disk. To emulate this environment in a file, I'd have to (before implementing a the b-tree), write a script to write to random locations and use say a linked list to keep track of what parts of the file haven't been written to. I just wanted to know if there was a way to leverage how the OS knows where to write and read on disk.